# CSS Responsive Percentage bug

Tags: css, google-chrome, responsive-design, percentage

Is there any solution how to avoid 1px "border" issue gap in Chrome and Firefox ? I have a grid by 4 columns each column is 25% inside is image that is fitting 100% width of parent div. When you changing a viewport and resizing browser sometimes you see on certain size 1px white gap. Probably it's because of wrong calculation percentage by browser. Did somebody solve this issue?

Comment: It's floated, doesn't solve this issue, in Safari is ok.

Comment: Without seeing your code, this is a guess, but can you try adding * { box-sizing: border-box } to your CSS?

Comment: yes i'm using it already, doesn't solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is put a wrapper around the elements inside of the `div` and set the width to 101% and then on the parent `div` (the original wrapper) you can set it to `overflow: hidden` like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="big-poppa"> <!-- Original Wrapper -->
    <div class="little-momma"> <!-- New Wrapper -->
        <div class="this-little-piggie market"></div>
        <div class="this-little-piggie home"></div>
        <div class="this-little-piggie roast-beef"></div>
        <div class="this-little-piggie none"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.big-poppa { width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; overflow: hidden; }
.little-momma { width: 101%; }
.this-little-piggie { width: 25%; float: left; height: 40px; }

.market { background: #eee; }
.home { background: #999; }
.roast-beef { background: #666; }
.none { background: #333; }
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YLJmE/

Comment: just to be sure, can you tell me exactly on which one i should put 101% ?  my structure is like this : div.category-list > article (width:25%) > div.inner > img (needs to fill 100% of article .... many thanks

Comment: You would need to add a new wrapper around the `article` tags. Then target that tag with your CSS and add the new `width: 101%`

Comment: Unfortunatelly this is not solving my issue,the image still gets white "border" gap sometimes. Maybe your solution is solving this problem but not when you have 100% image filling the div without padding or margin between each other image.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: here: http://d.pr/i/WZ8G this is between the images on certain google chrome window size, im using latest version of chrome. i think it's browser bug, because i was trying it on similar site and its doing this as well there. Just in Safari 7.0 is ok

Comment: Ah I see! You could try taking the width off of the article tag and putting it on the imgs? Or possibly making the images backgrounds for the article tags

Comment: Will try, the problem with the images width is that i need put overlay over them on hover so i have to keep it as it is now. Maybe the backgrounds..thanks a lot!

Comment: Hate Google for this :(